# Angular Js routing stopped working on changing versions

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am developing an angular application. Till today I was using angular 1.7 and angular-route 1.2. Because of new feature, I had to add angular-animate and angular-sanitize. After adding above js files I started getting the following error:

```
    Error: $injector:unpr
Unknown Provider
Unknown provider: $$HashMapProvider <- $$HashMap <- $$animateQueue <- $animate <- $compile <- $$animateQueue
```

To resolve the issue I changed the versions of all of angular libraries (angular, angular-route, angular-sanitize, angular-animate) to 1.2. 
After that I am not able to see the html given in

```
myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/search", {
            templateUrl: "views/search.html",
            controller: "SearchController"
        });
    // .otherwise({redirectTo: "/main"});
});
```

Please suggest how can I rectify it.

Comment: What version of angular-animate and angular-sanitize did you previously install?

Comment: I wasn't using angular-animate and angular-sanitize previously. I just added them yesterday, and then saw the aforementioned issue.

Comment: I mean when you added them, what versions did you add?

Comment: 1.2.0 for both angular-animate and angular-sanitize

Comment: You need those versions to match that of angular, which is 1.7

Comment: Initially, I was using 1.7 for angular-js. Then I switched all (angular-js, angular-animate, angular-sanitize) to 1.2.0.

Comment: What I am saying is that for 1.7, you would need all of them to be 1.7. You cannot have angularjs at 1.7 and have angular-animate and angular-sanitize at 1.2.

Comment: Day X - angularjs-1.7, Day Y- angular-js 1.2, angular-animate 1.2, angular-sanitize-1.2

Comment: Thanks @CoolestNerdIII Upgraded all to 1.7.0. It worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the answer from the comment section to the answer, there is a problem with running a different version of angular with angular-animate and angular-sanitize.

Both angular-animate and angular-sanitize need to be running the same version of angularjs, so they both need to run version 1.7.0.

Glad I could help a bit!